# Animation when adding a class not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, hide, show

I have a JQuery and CSS3 snippet to create a "scrolled into view animation". What's suppose to happen is it doesn't start the animation unless the class **animated** has the class **visible**. What keeps happening though is it adds the class **visible** but the animation doesn't trigger. I've tested this in all browsers and the only one that seems to do it correctly is Safari. I'd like to make this cross-browser compatible. Any help would be great!

Here is a fiddle of the snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/M6VLL/

Here is the JS:

```
(function(e){e.fn.visible=function(t,n,r){var i=e(this).eq(0),s=i.get(0),o=e(window),u=o.scrollTop(),a=u+o.height(),f=o.scrollLeft(),l=f+o.width(),c=i.offset().top,h=c+i.height(),p=i.offset().left,d=p+i.width(),v=t===true?h:c,m=t===true?c:h,g=t===true?d:p,y=t===true?p:d,b=n===true?s.offsetWidth*s.offsetHeight:true,r=r?r:"both";if(r==="both")return!!b&&m<=a&&v>=u&&y<=l&&g>=f;else if(r==="vertical")return!!b&&m<=a&&v>=u;else if(r==="horizontal")return!!b&&y<=l&&g>=f}})(jQuery)

jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {

  jQuery(".animated").each(function(i, el) {
    var el = jQuery(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("visible"); 
    }
  });

});
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.animated { opacity: 0;}
.animated.visible {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  opacity: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what is your problem using the dev tools.

You set initially:

```
.slideInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

and your idea is that this won't do anything because you haven't set the remaining porperties.

But, if you look at the real properties (with dev tools), you will see that the remaining properties are set to

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
```

That means that the animation is already running !!

When you set the .visible class, then you change some of the animation properties, but it's too late, the animation has already finished.

Comment: That does seem to be the problem. I've been messing around with the properties but can't seem to have it activate when the class "visible" is added. I got it to work now in Firefox but still no luck in getting it to rework in Chrome and work in IE. Any ideas? Here is the updated fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6ELFY/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an animation for this, you can just use transitions. I'd also use `translateX(-100%)` rather than what you have so you're sure it goes the necessary amount and never goes further than it has to. To make it cross browser you just have to add the other prefixes. I also used an `else` statement to make it go back to its default location when the page is scrolled up or down

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6VLL/2/)

Comment: The reason why I have it set up this way is because I use Animate.css by Daneden. I build WP Themes and I've been trying to get it set up for customization and being able to use all the different effects. This use to work in both Chrome and Safari but never IE or FF. Now I'm trying to get it to work in all browsers. I also have it set up purposely to only trigger once.